# Is it possible to speed up computation of Gramian matrix in PyTorch by only computing the upper triangular part?

Tags: optimization, pytorch, transpose, matrix-multiplication

I am trying to improve efficiency of the computation of a (Gramian)[https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Gram_matrix] matrix in pytorch. The naive implementation is `matrix.T @ matrix`, this matrix symmetrical and therefore it feels like we can speed up things by computing only the upper triangular part and then copying. Of course this could only be implemented more efficiently by using a small amount of functions from `torch`. Note that in some SVD algorithm this is used, this is why I believe that torch may have very efficient implementation of this computation, the question is more if this is accessible to users or if it is only implemented in `C`.
For dimensions, in my cases the matrix is of shape `[m,n]` with `n` small and `m` huge, therefore computing a lot of `m` by `m` inner product is bad but taking a upper triangular matrix of shape `[n,n]` to a symmetrical of shape `[n,n]` is fast.

I went through the list of functions implemented in `torch` and couldn't figure a way to combine functions there to get what I want.